# nanopb - what is Person_PhoneNumber_FIELDLIST macro?

Tags: c, nanopb

[Docs:](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb/blob/master/docs/concepts.md)

```
#define Person_PhoneNumber_FIELDLIST(X, a) \
X(a, STATIC,   REQUIRED, STRING,   number,            1) \
X(a, STATIC,   OPTIONAL, UENUM,    type,              2)
```

I do not see this macro being used.

Is there a use for this for a user of the API?

Comment: Is an [X-Macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)

Comment: the macro is `Person_PhoneNumber_FIELDLIST` there is no macro called `FIELDLIST`